# Unable to use jq arg as select filter

Tags: sh, jq

I'm trying to use jq's `--arg` syntax to pass a variable from the shell to a jq filter.

If I run the following command, the jq query works as expected:

```
TS_SEC_START=1534574204 \
kubectl -n istio-system logs deployment/flagger --tail=50 | grep '^{' | \
jq --arg TS_SEC_START 1534574204 --arg SVC "${SERVICE_NAME}.${RELEASE_NAMESPACE}" \
-s 'map(select(.ts | (split(".")[0] + "Z") | fromdateiso8601 > ($TS_SEC_START | tonumber)) | select(.canary == "mysvc.prod"))'
```

-->

```
Found 3 pods, using pod/flagger-6dc6fd7d85-z294g
[
  {
    "level": "error",
    "ts": "2021-08-16T02:41:34.128Z",
    "caller": "controller/scheduler.go:163",
    "msg": "Canary mysvc.prod not found",
    "canary": "mysvc.prod",
    "stacktrace": "github.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.(*Controller).advanceCanary\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/scheduler.go:163\ngithub.com/fluxcd/flagger/pkg/controller.CanaryJob.Start.func1\n\t/workspace/pkg/controller/job.go:39"
  }
]
```

However, when I try to pass `mysvc.prod` as an arg, I receive 0 responses.

```
TS_SEC_START=1534574204 SERVICE_NAME=mysvc RELEASE_NAMESPACE=prod \
kubectl -n istio-system logs deployment/flagger --tail=50 | grep '^{' | \
jq --arg TS_SEC_START 1534574204 --arg SVC "${SERVICE_NAME}.${RELEASE_NAMESPACE}" \
-s 'map(select(.ts | (split(".")[0] + "Z") | fromdateiso8601 > ($TS_SEC_START | tonumber)) | select(.canary == $SVC))'
```

I've tried a few different options here, e.g. `.canary == "$SVC"` and `.canary == "$SERVICE_NAME.$RELEASE_NAMESPACE" but I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

-->

```
Found 3 pods, using pod/flagger-6dc6fd7d85-z294g
[]
```

Comment: How exactly are `SERVICE_NAME` and `RELEASE_NAMESPACE` being set? `SVC` may not have the exact value you think it does. `jq -n --arg SVC "a.b" '"a.b" == $f'` outputs `true`.

Comment: I've added the `sh` tag since I believe this issue isn't solely a `jq` issue, but a shell-scripting one.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't do this:

```
MYVAR=12345 printf "%s\n" "$MYVAR"
```

When you prefix a shell command with `MYVAR=12345` you are modifying the environment that is passed to that process, in this case `printf`. However, the `$MYVAR` expression is expanded in the shell and no `MYVAR` variable ever exists in the shell.

Furthermore, when you set variables like this, they are only passed to *that command*, not the entire pipeline.

So in this example:

```
TS_SEC_START=1534574204 \
SERVICE_NAME=mysvc \
RELEASE_NAMESPACE=prod \
kubectl -n istio-system logs deployment/flagger --tail=50 | \
    grep '^{' | \
    jq \
        --arg TS_SEC_START 1534574204 \
        --arg SVC "${SERVICE_NAME}.${RELEASE_NAMESPACE}" \
        -s \
        '
          map(
            select(
              .ts |
              (split(".")[0] + "Z") |
              fromdateiso8601 > ($TS_SEC_START | tonumber)
            ) |
            select(.canary == $SVC)
          )
        '
```

The three environment variables are visible to `kubectl` and nothing else. They are not visible to `grep` or `jq` (although neither of them are looking for such environment variables in the first place) and they are not visible to the shell itself as it expands those commands.